# What's this line of code? (structuring/designing a js web app)

Tags: design-patterns, web-applications

Quite a strange question here eh...
I'm trying to understand better how generally the js code is structured for web apps.

I often saw something like this line on code starts (but now for some reason I can't find a real example):

```
var SOME = SOME || {}
```

Or something similar.. I now it's vague, but I'm sure is somehwat a common pattern and if someone of you is used to web apps will recognize it..

My question is: I'm quite sure that line of code starts some kind of pattern. Do you recognize it? Can you tell me what's the pattern?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically

`var SOME = SOME || {}`

means set local `SOME` (i.e var SOME) to point to an existing global variable named `SOME` (i.e. = SOME), if it's not NULL. If global SOME is NULL, then set local SOME to a new object `{}`

It's a shortcut way of saying

```
var SOME = {};

if (window.SOME != NULL) {
    SOME = window.SOME
}
```

EDIT:

OK, often this pattern is used when working with modules. For example

> Foo.js

```
window.appModule = {};
```

> Bar.js

```
   var appModule = appModule || {};

   appModule.newFunction = function () { //.... Whatever. };

   window.appModule = appModule;
```

Basically we want to use an existing appModule instance, or create a new one if it doesn't yet exist. Here we are extending an existing module instance by adding a new function to it. So really, this pattern is just a handy way of making sure there is an instance of an object created, if it does not already exist.

It's not a major pattern really, just a convenient shortcut.

EDIT:

Found this example just now:

```
var MODULE = (function (my) {
    // add capabilities...

    return my;
}(MODULE || {}));
```

Notice the pattern used at the bottom. Again, it's a handy way of saying use an existing `MODULE` or new-up another for me, and then pass that into the `function (my)`.

Comment: Ok, I knew what it does. But my question is slightly different: do you recognize what it's often used for, in structuring web apps code blocks (maybe modules?)?

Comment: Thank you. As per another example for future readers, take a look at this classic: [https://github.com/tastejs/todomvc/tree/gh-pages/architecture-examples/backbone] each js file start with `var app = app || {};`

Answer (score 1):

Avoids SOME being null.

It's shortcircuiting. Basically, if SOME is NULL, it will become {}, so it's great for initializing.

```
var myVar = valueThatCouldBeNull || WhateverIWantToInitInSaidCase
```

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/3Hb7H/1/).